# Determinant: Effect on changing entry in a matrix on Cofactor Expansion [GStrang 5.2.22]

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
I can't discern why $N_n = S_n - S_{n - 1}$ from the answer (I define these below).

I computed: $S_1 = 3, S_2 = 8$.
By cofactor expansion along the $3$rd column (WLOG, I could've picked row):
$S_3 = 1\cdot(-1)^{2 + 3} \begin{vmatrix}
    3 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix} + 3\cdot(-1)^{3 + 3}\begin{vmatrix}
    3 & 1 \\
    1 & 3 \\
    \end{vmatrix} = 21.$

Let $N$ be the $S_i$ with the change of the $(1, 1)$ entry to $2$.
Then $N_1 = |\color{#009900}{2}|, N_2 = 5 = S_2 - S_1.$
By cofactor expansion along the $3$rd column,
$N_3 = 1\cdot(-1)^{2 + 3} \begin{vmatrix}
    \color{#009900}{2} & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix} + 3\cdot(-1)^{3 + 3}\begin{vmatrix}
    \color{#009900}{2} & 1 \\
    1 & 3 \\
    \end{vmatrix} = 13 = S_3 - S_2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $S_n$. Cofactor expand along the first row and notice that the $(1,1)$ cofactor is precisely $S_{n-1}$. That means we can write
$$S_n = 3S_{n-1} + \text{remaining terms}$$
where "remaining terms" are the other terms of the expansion (which do not really matter to us). Changing the $3$ to a $2$ will not affect the remaining terms of the expansion, so we get
$$\color{green}{N_n = 2S_{n-1} + \text{remaining terms (Same as those in $S_n$)}}$$

Now substitute $N_n$ into $S_n$:
$$S_n = S_{n-1} + \color{green}{2S_{n-1} + \text{remaining terms}}
\\ =  S_{n-1} + \color{green}{N_n}$$

The net effect of the change is to subtract $S_{n-1}$ from $S_n$. Therefore
$$N_n = S_n - S_{n-1}$$

Comment: +1. Thank you. Could you please enlarge on "the net effect of the change ..."? How did you perceive that? Is it 100% exactly what I added in my edit above? Please feel free to emend my edit. Will you please to respond in your answer; comments are harder to read.

Comment: @LePressentiment Yes you are correct in your edits.